# How to draw content behind parent View in Custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ondraw, viewgroup

I am using this ArcMenu https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu

Please check the code and the image of the ArcMenu on the github page

This custom view is arranged this way ->
ArcMenu[View] has Children -> ArcLayout[ViewGroup] has children -> ImageViews (to hold the icons for menu)

I am trying to draw colored arc behind the Arclayout. I am doing this in the onDraw

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
    if(isExpanded()){
        Log.d("ArcLayout","onDraw(Canvas)");
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(colorOne);
            paint.setAlpha(125);

            canvas.drawArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, paint);
            //Dimensions of rect are set in OnMeasure 
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Now the problem is that the OnDraw gets called for all the children and the logic for drawing is same for the parentView and children view. I want the Colored Arc to be drawn behind the parent view and not the children(Imageviews).

Rect dimensions are top=0, left=0, right=getMeasuredWidth(), bottom=getMeasuredHeight().

When the call to canvas.onDraw is made, top Left of the rect becomes relative to child i.e 0,0 of the child and the not the parent. The result is a colored arc behind the child and not the parent.

How should I ensure that the colored arc gets drawn behind the Parent view only?

Comment: override ArcLayout.dispatchDraw then

Comment: I tried the overriding ArcLayout.dispatchDraw but the result is the same. dispatchDraw gets called multiple times (for drawing the child imageviews) and the arc is drawn relative to the last child.

Comment: do your draw stuff before calling super.dispatchDraw

Comment: and of course it has nothing to do with the last child, the Canvas is not translated in any way